# Why does an All-in-one Printer have a scanning glass, when it can scan with an Automatic Document Feeder?

Tags: printer

[image]

Isn't the scanning glass in [Fig. 1](http://www.repsunny.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/HP-Officejet-Pro-8710-2.jpg) redundant? [Fig. 2](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71gDkTRWzpL._SL1500_.jpg) also features the HP OfficeJet 8710.

Comment: Ever try to suck a book through that little slot?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. I was stupid.

Comment: @fixer1234 lol, just spit my mouthful of food all over the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The scanning glass is useful where documents dont fit into the sheet feeder - like books, A3 docs, multiple text receipts, fragile documents, small things like photos.

Also if you want a high res scan of a small area, its a lot easier to do it on the glass.

Comment: Also: ADFs are notoriously unreliable unless the paper is in near-perfect condition. Even if the document "fits", it may be impossible to scan it with an ADF.